# Embed a pdf document into asp webpage

Tags: asp-classic

I used the following code to embed and display a pdf document in a .asp webpage not in asp.net,the code displays the frame but not the pdf, can someone tell me where i was wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<iframe height="1400" width="1000" src="C:/proof.pdf">If you see this text, your browser cannot display this document. Click <a href="C:/proof.pdf"> this link </a> to view it separately.</iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you are storing that file is a big problem and something you should likely fix. What you mainly want to fix is this section

```
src="C:/proof.pdf"
```

I honestly do not care if your site does give access to the root of your C: drive it is a terrible practice to ever let that happen. Your site should not have access to any files outside your inetpub folder. What you should do immediately is move this file to a resource folder within your website. Assuming you have not changed any of the default settings this pdf would now be stored in

```
C:/wwwroot/inetpub/resources/proof.pdf
```

Once you do this though you should also change the src value to a relative path. If you followed my previous advice that path should look like this

```
src="../resources/proof.pdf"
```

That should both work fine and be much safer for your hosting computer.